# What is the purpose of [] operator while opening a file in python

Tags: python, file

I see the following syntax in one of the python files. I can understand that it is reading the file. But I am not sure what the [0][0] are used for

```
lines = open (config[0][0], 'r').readlines()
```

My config file looks like

```
py0:max0
py1:max1
py2
py3
```

Could someone please share your comments

Comment: config is a list of list, config[0][0] looks like it holds the name of the file you want to open

Comment: The `config` here is a variable (seems a 2D list )? can you show that how you have created it?

Comment: config[0][0] is in short give me the first item in the second list from the first item in the first list in the config variable (reading the variable from right to left)

Comment: When i print len(config[0][0]) it gives me 19, and for len(config[0][1]) it gives me 0. How can i correlate these with the config file.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the config file, or with the process of opening a file in general, or otherwise with files at all; it has **everything** to do with what the `config` data structure you're getting the filename from is. Without showing how that structure is defined, this question is incomplete.

Comment: @user2532296, have you taken into account what `print repr(config)` emits?

Comment: it results in [('../connections/conn'), []] .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small modification makes the code better understandable:

```
filename = config[0][0]
lines = open(filename, 'r').readlines()
```

You obtain the file name from a variable that contains a list of lists, and then this file is opened and all lines read.